# How to customize schedule in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a containerized spring boot application.
Currently there are 10+ instances of same spring boot application.
Application is deployed in Azure and based on load pods may come up and go down.

Within that application i have scheduled a task to perform an activity.
This activity is a high memory intensive task.

Since I have 10+ instances of same application running, when schedule get triggered say Example 09:00 AM, all my pods are performing scheduled activity at same time.

Because of this memory is not sufficient and pods are going down.

Is there a way to handle this in spring boot?
Say for example since I have schedule at 09:00 AM, instead of all 10 instances starting at 09:00 AM I have to start three instances schedule @09:00 other three @09:01 and remaining @09:02

Can i schedule like this in spring boot?
Or Is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: use Shedlock. see these links [link1](https://rieckpil.de/lock-scheduled-tasks-with-shedlock-and-spring-boot/) & [link2](http://buraktas.com/spring-shedlock-tutorial/). shedlock with [postconstruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67567624/how-to-call-scheduled-method-in-only-one-instance-using-postconstruct)

Comment: You can also use something like Quartz Scheduler to synchronize tasks in clustered environment

Comment: I think you can use ShedLock to do this https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring